# Period function not working as expected in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the below scenario where i have to correct/merge the incorrect history handled records:

```
Acct_Id     status_cd   Start_Dttm       End_Dttm    ROLE_CD
1,108,389,774   11     6/10/2009 18:03  7/18/2018 4:11   6
1,108,389,774   11     7/18/2018 4:11   8/8/2018 7:18    6
1,108,389,774   8       8/8/2018 7:18   ?                6
```

I have to merge the top two records into one where the history is wrong.
I m using the below query.

```
SELECT acct_id,acct_status_cd,acct_status_start_dttm  ,acct_status_end_dttm ,acct_status_role_cd,run_id, data_source_type_cd,

       BEGIN(PD) AS  acct_status_start_dttm , NULLIF(END(PD), TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00') AS acct_status_end_dttm
    FROM
    ( 
       SELECT NORMALIZE -- 
          acct_id,trim(acct_status_cd) as acct_status_cd ,acct_status_start_dttm  ,acct_status_end_dttm ,acct_status_role_cd,run_id, data_source_type_cd,
          PERIOD(acct_status_start_dttm,COALESCE(acct_status_end_dttm, TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00')) AS PD
       FROM dp_dqmt.acct_stat_hh    
       where acct_status_start_dttm < acct_status_end_dttm  
    ) AS DT
```

can anyone tell whats wrong here?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? What do you mean `merge the top two records into one`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the date columns as they're not the same and thus `normalize` will not combine both rows:

```
SELECT acct_id,acct_status_cd
   -- acct_status_start_dttm  ,acct_status_end_dttm ,
     ,acct_status_role_cd,run_id, data_source_type_cd,

       Begin(PD) AS  acct_status_start_dttm , NullIf(End(PD), TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00') AS acct_status_end_dttm
    FROM
    ( 
       SELECT NORMALIZE -- 
          acct_id,Trim(acct_status_cd) AS acct_status_cd ,
          -- acct_status_start_dttm  ,acct_status_end_dttm ,
          acct_status_role_cd,run_id, data_source_type_cd,
          PERIOD(acct_status_start_dttm,Coalesce(acct_status_end_dttm, TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00')) AS PD
       FROM dp_dqmt.acct_stat_hh    
       WHERE acct_status_start_dttm < acct_status_end_dttm  
    ) AS DT
```

The `where` will also remove the last row with a NULL acct_status_end_dttm unless you change it to

```
WHERE acct_status_start_dttm < Coalesce(acct_status_end_dttm, TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Hi Dnoeth,
I am still getting 3 rows for that particular sample. As the major col is acct_status_cd and it is 11 for both the top two rows. They both should be merged to one.

Comment: Are all four columns equal: `acct_id,Trim(acct_status_cd) ,
          acct_status_role_cd,run_id, data_source_type_cd`?

Comment: Ohh ..got it..run_id was not the same. I had modified the query and it's working fine now. Thanks a lot!!